# Difference between installing and using virtualenv "globally from source" and using it "locally from source"

Tags: virtualenv

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv
says

To install globally from source:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ [sudo] python setup.py install
```

To use locally from source (and not be insecure as described in the warning above):

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python virtualenv.py myVE
```

Could someone please elaborate on the differences between installing and using virtualenv globally and using it locally (I am under the impression this is different than running virtualenv --no-site-packages)? Why is using it locally considered more secure?

Comment: Yes, it's different, as it concerns the `virtualenv` binary itself, not virtual Python environments you create after installing. I.e., whichever way you choose, it won't influence virtual environments that you create using `virtualenv`.

Comment: (Installing globally generally means sudo, and programs ran with sudo have much more privileges than if you run them locally with your rights. For better security it's often recommended to install software locally under your user permissions, and some programs explicitly provide a way to be used without global installation.)